# Pasar datos de un ActivityA a un FragmentA que esta dentro de otra ActivityB en Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment

Necesito su ayuda, Talvez alguien sepa. ¿Cómo pasar datos de una ActivityA (un valor texto de un textview) a un FragmentA que esta dentro de otra ActivityB(este contiene tablayout y los fragmentsA, B y C parecido a whatsapp) y ese valor del fragmentoA pasarle al FragmentB en Kotlin?.

En la ActivityA tengo 2 Cardviews, cada uno tiene un TextView, el android:text, les puse el nombre "Item1"  y "Item2" respectivamente. Y quiero que dependiendo del cardview que hago click poder pasar y mostrar el nombre del respectivo Item1 o Item2 que contiene el cardview al fragmentA y fragmentB que estan dentro de la ActivityB en kotlin. He visto algunos que usan bundle, sharedpref. Pero consigo error, o no obtengo el nombre del respectivo item al hacer click.

aqui texview 1:

```
 <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nombre_del_itemA"
                    android:text="Item1"              
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

aqui texview 2:

```
<TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nombre_del_itemB"
                    android:text="Item2"                
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Yo quiero mostrar el texto del TextView: Item1 o Item2 dependiendo cual cardview hago click en el Fragment A y ese valor del FragmentA mostrar también FragmentB que estan en la ActivityB

ActivityA:

```
class ActivityA : AppCompatActivity() {

    var tv1: TextView? = null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.a_activity)

tv1 = findViewById<View>(R.id.nombre_item_1) as TextView

boton_continuar.setOnClickListener {
val nombre_item = (tv1 as TextView).text.toString()

val intent = Intent (this@ActivityA, TablayoutActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("NombreItem", nombre_item)
startActivity(intent)
```

Aqui la ActivityB, contiene Tablayout y los Fragments donde quiero conseguir los datos de la ActivityA. A esta ActivityB le puse nombre: Tablayout.

```
class TablayoutActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val adapter by lazy { ViewPagerAdapter(this) }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tablayout)
        pager.adapter = adapter
        val tabLayoutMediator = TabLayoutMediator(tab_layout,pager,
            TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy { tab, position ->
                when(position){
                    0-> {
                        tab.text = "TAB1"
                    }
                    1->{
                        tab.text = "TAB2"
                    }
                    2->{
                        tab.text = "TAB3"
                    }
                }
            })
        tabLayoutMediator.attach()
    }
}
```

Aqui el ViewPagerAdapter.kt

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(fa: FragmentActivity): FragmentStateAdapter(fa) {
    companion object{
        private const val ARG_OBJECT = "object"
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = 3

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {

        return when(position){
            0->{ FragmentA()}
            1->{ FragmentB()}
            2->{ FragmentC()}
            else-> FragmentA()
        }

    }
}
```

Y aqui el codigo del FragmentA donde quiero conseguir el valor del textview de la ActivityA:

```
class FragmentA : Fragment() {
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val vista= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_A, container, false)

//¿qué codigo debo usar?
//aqui pruebo con intent pero no funciona, no lo reconoce. intent si funciona para pasar datos entre activities pero al querer pasar datos de una actividad al fragment no funciona.

val intent = intent
val marca = intent.getStringExtra("NombreItem")

return vista
}
```

Espero que alguien pueda ayudar. Saludos a toda la comunidad :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo pasar tus argumentos al crear el fragment desde tu adapter

Activity:

```
class TablayoutActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    //Pasa al adapter los extras recibidos del primer activity
    private val adapter by lazy{ViewPagerAdapter(this,intent.extras)}

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tablayout)
        
        pager.adapter = adapter
        val tabLayoutMediator = TabLayoutMediator(tab_layout,pager,
                TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy { tab, position ->
                    when(position){
                        0-> {
                            tab.text = "TAB1"
                        }
                        1->{
                            tab.text = "TAB2"
                        }
                        2->{
                            tab.text = "TAB3"
                        }
                    }
                })
        tabLayoutMediator.attach()
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(fa: FragmentActivity,val extras:Bundle?): FragmentStateAdapter(fa) {
    companion object{
        private const val ARG_OBJECT = "object"
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = 3

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {

        return when(position){
            0->{ val fragA=FragmentA()
                fragA.arguments=extras
                fragA
            }
            1->{ val fragB=FragmentB()
                fragB.arguments=extras
                fragB}
            else-> { val fragA=FragmentA()
                fragA.arguments=extras
                fragA
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
class FragmentA : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false)
        val marca = arguments?.getString("NombreItem","")

        return vista
    }

}
```

Comment: Excelente @danms07 me sirvió tu ayuda. Hoy es mi cumpleaños y hoy lo probé y si me funcionó. Lo único que faltó fue, para que el valor capturado se muestre en donde quiero ya sea dentro de un EditText, o TextView. Agregué en el FragmentA los códigos: 
var textomostrar:TextView? = null al empiezo y debajo de la línea: 
val marca = arguments?.getString("NombreItem","") agregué: 
textomostrar = vista.findViewById(R.id.your_subject) 
textomostrar!!.setText(marca).toString() Muchísimas gracias. Saludos.